# Isn't convention tag meant to allow discussion on opinions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, tags, close-reasons, reopen

I recently asked [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/778186/330899) question which got closed because its answer was based on opinions. But that was exactly the point of my question, and hence the usage of tag of "convention". So I am not sure why it got closed.

Answer (score 5):

Speaking in general, the existence/non-existence of a tag does not imply that a certain question is on-topic/off-topic, respectively. This is instead decided by the Phys.SE community, e.g. via vote-to-close/vote-to-reopen, or e.g. via Phys.Meta policy posts.